# {% if app.user and is_granted('...') %} throws exception on 404 page

Tags: symfony, routes, http-status-code-404

I am using Symfony 2.7 and using `is_granted('...')` throws an exception when being used on a custom `404` error page.

I am aware that since Symfony 2.1 routing is done before security:

> The Firewall listener is now registered after the Router listener.
>   This means that specific Firewall URLs (like /login_check and /logout)
>   must now have proper routes defined in your routing configuration.
>   Also, if you have a custom 404 error page, make sure that you do not
>   use any security related features such as is_granted on it.

See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#security

Thus `is_granted('...')` **alone** will not work. However the solution that is discussed in many different threads is, to check `app.user` first:

```
{% extends app.user and is_granted('ROLE_USER') ? 'AppBundle::private.html.twig' : 'AppBundle::public.html.twig' %}
{% if app.user and is_granted('...') %} ...

instead of 

{% extends is_granted('ROLE_USER') ? 'AppBundle::private.html.twig' : 'AppBundle::public.html.twig' %}
{% if is_granted('...') %} ...
```

**But this is exactly what I already do.**

While this check works fine on all public pages (e.g. `mypage.xy/notexisting`) it will fail with for all pages within the user area (user is logged in, e.g. `mypage.xy/user/notexisting`)

What is the difference and how can I get this code running for all pages?

Comment: Have you tried using parenthesis around `app.user and is_granted('ROLE_USER')`?

Comment: You mean `{% extends ((app.user) and (is_granted('ROLE_USER')))...` for example? The result is the same.